# How to add column to SQL Server bcp query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in SQL Server, when I write this query:

```
select ANUMBER 
from CDRTABLE
```

it shows me data, but I want to add new column to result change that query to this:

```
select '028', ANUMBER 
from CDRTABLE
```

This query adds a new column to query result, so I write this bcp query for saving results to a text file:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT rtrim(ltrim(ANUMBER)),rtrim(ltrim(BNUMBER)),rtrim(ltrim(DATE)),rtrim(ltrim(TIME)),rtrim(ltrim(DURATION))  FROM [myTestReport].[dbo].[CDRTABLE]"  queryout f:\newOUTPUT.txt -S DESKTOP-A5CFJSH\MSSQLSERVER1 -Umyusername -Pmypassword -f "f:\myFORMAT.fmt"  '
```

and my format file is this:

```
 9.0
    5
    1 SQLNCHAR 0 5 "," 1 ANUMBER ""
    2 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 2 BNUMBER ""
    3 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 3 DATE ""
    4 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 4 TIME ""
    5 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "\r\n" 5 DURATION ""
```

Everything is ok, but I want add new column to bcp result, for example add `'028'` to bcp query result. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for advice on how to change your format file to accommodate the new column? Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx help?

Comment: @BenThul thanks,i'm look that link and solve my problem,please post your comment to i vote up and accept you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it looks like you're adding a character string to the front of the select, something like this should work:

```
 9.0
    6
    1 SQLCHAR  0 3 "," 1 NEWCOLUMN "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    2 SQLNCHAR 0 5 "," 2 ANUMBER ""
    3 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 3 BNUMBER ""
    4 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 4 DATE ""
    5 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 5 TIME ""
    6 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "\r\n" 6 DURATION ""
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx for more details on the format of the format file.